# Image not show properly, I want to show like Facebook image post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, imageview

I have to tried all type of content mode, Third party and lots of googling.
But, not success for me.
I want to show like Facebook image post.
We are post image in facebook, facebook show properly images and fill the image very properly into image view.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your requirement? and what exactly you have done till now?

Comment: Did you check imageViewContentMode? try setting content mode to AspectFit/Fill. If possible give more insight on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow steps

1. setImage to UIImageView (with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`)
2. get imageSize `(CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size)`
3. UIImageView resize. `[imageView sizeThatFits:imageSize]`
4. move position where you want.

   ```
       CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;
       [imageView sizeThatFits:imageSize];
       CGPoint imageViewCenter = imageView.center;
        imageViewCenter.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.contentView.frame);
       [imageView setCenter:imageViewCenter];
   ```

Comment: Thanks @junaidsidhu. I want to fill the image like Facebook.Any type of image(like height > width, width(height*2)>height) fill very properly by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

set UIImageView size == image (ratio):

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func setImage(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

    let imageAspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
    let screenAspectRatio = screenSize.width / screenSize.height

    if imageAspectRatio > screenAspectRatio {
        widthConstraint.constant = min(image.size.width, screenSize.width)
        heightConstraint.constant = widthConstraint.constant / imageAspectRatio
    }
    else {
        heightConstraint.constant = min(image.size.height, screenSize.height)
        widthConstraint.constant = heightConstraint.constant * imageAspectRatio
    }
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

reference link [AutoLayout: UIImageView and Aspect Fit content mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142558/autolayout-uiimageview-and-aspect-fit-content-mode)